# Searching for a line in a jpg file Python

Tags: python, image, line, ocr

I'm interested in using Python to detect a vertical line dividing a scanned page in two. I have a series of these scanned pages, and I need to split them in half along a black line. I know how to split them using ImageMagick, I just need to be able to detect the line, which is positioned slightly differently (due to scanning) in each of the images. I've looked into using a Hough Transform, but I wasn't able to get it to work because of all of the text that surrounds the images. 
I can't post images, but you can find some here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6oYP6Nnjm4bFhYQzFSdnpPTTg/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_6oYP6Nnjm4OGFQekM1SHBDN0E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: CAUTION: That linked PDF has a massive size of, **119MB**, you can try uploading images on google drive and provide the relevant link here.

Comment: You could add all the pixels in each vertical column of the image and choose the one that adds up to the smallest number - i.e. the darkest one. P.S. i can't see your picture so I am guessing. Maybe convert to greyscale first.

Comment: Hi, I just uploaded some images, sorry for the original PDF!

Comment: As for the vertical columns, the slashes run at a bit of a slant, so I'm not so sure that'd work in this specific case. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use something like template matching. What you're looking for is a vertical stripe of black pixels surrounded by white pixels. Locally, the image should look like:

```
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1
```

So run this template over your image and find places where it matches.

Here are the steps I'd take (using the scikit-image package):

0) (Optional) Reduce the size of the image by extracting a band around the center where you'd expect the line to be.

1) Define your template:

```
pattern = np.tile(np.array([1,1,0,1,1]), (3, 1))
```

2) Find the places where the image is similar to the pattern:

```
windows = skimage.util.view_as_windows(roi, pattern.shape)
diff = np.sum((windows - pattern)**2, axis=2).sum(axis=2)
```

3) Now define some threshold to determine whether a location is a match or not. Here I'm using 0.5:

```
rows, cols = np.nonzero(diff < .5)
```

4) There will be many matches, some of them spurious, but an overwhelming number of them will be correct. So form a histogram and find the bin with the largest number of entries:

```
counts, centers = np.histogram(cols, bins=40)
page_divider = centers[np.argmax(counts)]
```

This approach can be made more robust in a number of ways: by using a soft template, by using a kernel density estimator rather than a histogram, etc. But in my tests this worked well enough.